# Create popup if record insertion fails for user in MS ACCESS Form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a button that runs a macro that calls function "CheckRecordCount()" which then calls Sub Command1_Click.

I want a pop up if the form does not proceed to a new blank record (in other words a new record is not inserted).

I tried an error function but the error seems to execute regardless.

```
Public Function CheckRecordCount()
    Call Command1_Click
End Function

Private Sub Command1_Click()

    On Error GoTo FailedInsertion
   DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
   
FailedInsertion:

MsgBox "Fill out all fields and try again. Record insertion failed."

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem.

```
Public Function CheckRecordCount()
    Call Command1_Click

End Function

Private Sub Command1_Click()

   Dim varTotalBefore As Integer
   Dim varTotalAfter As Integer
   varTotalBefore = Forms![your form title].Form.Recordset.RecordCount
   On Error Resume Next
   DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
   On Error GoTo 0
   varTotalAfter = Forms![your form title].Form.Recordset.RecordCount
   
If varTotalAfter = varTotalBefore Then
MsgBox "Request submission failed. Ensure all fields are filled out and try again."
End If

If varTotalAfter > varTotalBefore Then
MsgBox "Request successfully submitted!"
End If

End Sub
```